# Какой корень в словах доход, расход и приход (церк.)?

Tags: корень-слова

Как делается морфемный и словообразовательный разбор этих слов? И какая у них основа: производная или непроизводная?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ.
 Существует забавное мнение, что мы понимаем друг друга только потому, что очень быстро говорим. Если остановимся и начнем вникать в смысл каждого слова, то общение не состоится, так как мы в своей обыденной жизни не привыкли пользоваться точными определениями. Но такие точные определения НУЖНЫ В ГРАММАТИКЕ, если мы хотим считать ее наукой.

Возьмем, к примеру,  определение непроизводных слов. В Грамматике говорится, что  это слова, которые, С ТОЧКИ ЗРЕНИЯ СОВРЕМЕННОГО СОСТОЯНИЯ ЯЗЫКА, не считаются образованными от других слов, то есть это немотивированные слова.  Теперь построим словообразовательную цепочку от глагола «ходить».  Вряд ли можно надеяться, что она будет бесконечной, где-нибудь да прервется. Вот слово "доход" в нее не вписывается и образует свое гнездо: доходный, доходность, подоходный. От «расход» образуется «расходный», от «расходовать» - «расходование», но это тоже самостоятельные слова.

И нам приходится считать их непроизводными, хотя состоят они из «живых» морфем. Далее у Тихонова мы читаем: ходить – походить (некоторое время) – поход. Вряд ли такую цепочку можно считать серьезной. (И дальше (страшно предположить!) дело дойдет и до «повара», но его  обсуждать мы лучше не будем).

А если эти слова непроизводные, то их нельзя делить на морфемы, и в то же время они явно состоят из этих морфем. И что делать? Я вполне понимаю эмоциональный настрой некоторых наших коллег. Мне тоже неприятно считать неразложимой основу слова «доход», если оно наглядно распадается на две части.

Так, может быть, стоит подправить теорию?
Хотя "доход и расход"  непроизводные, но как-то они образовались? Причем, образовались именно в современном языке. Мы просто сложили приставку ДО  со значением достижения и корень ХОД со значением движения и получили новое слово, определяющее  финансовые потоки. А почему бы и нет? Можно даже имя придумать для этого "нового" способа образования непроизводных слов - например, назовем его  сложноприставочным (обычно мы складываем корни, а здесь будем складывать приставку и корень).

Answer (score 3):

Доход — это прибыль, деньги дошли до личного кармана дельца и тп.
Расход — траты, деньги расходятся на текущие выплаты кредиторам, поставщикам, работникам...
Приход (деньги) — поступления (пришли) в кассу предприятия.
Приход (церк.) — община верующих, которые приходят в один храм и пользуются некоторыми правами для выбора *причта* (церковнослужителей).
Все указанные слова благополучно произошли от соответствующих глаголов: доходить, расходиться, приходить.
Поход — ход, я уже писал в комментарии к давешнему вопросу.
Всё это основы производные, как же иначе. Если их считать непроизводными, теория и преподавание русского языка могут превратиться в добровольное сумасшествие.
Корень **ход** — в любом случае.

Answer (score 3):

Этимологически веде корень -ход- от праслав.ход - движение, достижение, но в современном языке нельзя сказать доход - то, что дошло, это будет "народная этимология". В современном языке это немотивированное слово с непроизводной основой, корень доход/нул. оконч.

То же самое расход - не то,что разошлось, хотя этимологически так. Приход - не то, что пришло.Приход - первонач. "сходка для выборов старосты", затем "церковный приход" - община. Тоже немотивированная в совр. языке основа.

Посмотрите в Грамматическом словаре А.А.Зализняка, этот словарь сейчас действует как норма. Я его не скачала, если Вам надо, скачайте. В старых словарях будет по-разному. Но в школьном словообразовании  это уже непроизводные слова.

Comment: Это получается научная-высосанная-из-пальца-аргументация... Печальная тенденция к усложнению простых истин набирает силу, а после мы жалуемся на непонятливость учащейся молодежи. Русский язык элементарно сдохнет в недалеком будущем, и причиной тому будет подобное "научное творчество". Мягче сказать невозможно, господа преподаватели((((((( "Немотивированный наукообраз".  
Искусственный подход в различных учебных пособиях меняется постоянно, в зависимости от степени филочесотки; народное понимание корней родного языка должно быть вечным. Будет ли оно таким, ""крепко сомневаюсь""...

Comment: А по-Вашему - израсходовать - потратить,издержаться, антоним к "доход",  или , как в расходиться, исходиться -от  ходить, уйти? Или пустить в расход - от расходиться? Значения разошлись,мотивация потерялась.

Comment: Кажется, мотивация совсем в другом месте потерялась! Печально все это.  
Пустить в расход (расстрелять) - иносказание, новый смысл - "израсходовать человеческую единицу на благо общества". Не надо трогать корни, хлебнете горюшка.  
Совсем необязательно одно слово "происходит от другого слова" непосредственно. Слова рождаются ассоциативно, зачем делать из этого проблему для школьников и студентов?